# How to mySQL query based on matching column values?

Tags: php, mysql

I want the while loop to output based on matching column value of "id".

```
    $query = "SELECT s.id,s.last,s.first,s.course1,s.course2,s.course3
            ,e.id,e.last,e.first,e.course1,e.course2,e.course3
            FROM $startsem1 s
            JOIN $endsem1 e on s.id = e.id";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
         print_r($row); echo "<br><br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a join:

```
SELECT s.id,s.last,s.first,s.course1,s.course2,s.course3
      ,e.id,e.last,e.first,e.course1,e.course2,e.course3
  FROM $startsem1 s
  JOIN $endsem1 e on s.id = e.id
```

Comment: I edited my code above, but the while loop only outputs the courses from $endsem1, but not $startsem1.

Comment: try using alias for the column value like select s.id as sid, e.id as eid, that way might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You use binary operator `&`, not logical `&&` in the while loop condition.